# Symfony2 class loader doesnt work if path does not match folder structure?

Tags: symfony, classloader

Here is my current structure

plugins/

|---init.php

|---/plugin1/lib/

|---/plugin2/lib/

|---/Symfony/

I have my code like this:

```
set_include_path(DIR_FS_CATALOG.'plugins');

require_once(DIR_FS_CATALOG.'plugins/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php');

// load the class loader and dependency injection component
$loader = new Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader();

$loader->registerNamespaces(array('plugins\\plugin1'  => __DIR__.'/plugins/plugin1/lib', 'plugins' => DIR_FS_CATALOG.'plugins'));
$loader->registerNamespace('Symfony',__DIR__.'/plugins');

$loader->register();


use plugins\plugin1\MyClass;

MyClass::init();
```

**Fatal error: Class 'plugins\plugin1\MyClass' not found**

I wonder what did I do wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Symfony2 class loader is PSR-0 compliant (https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) which means, that your namespaces must reflect your file system structure.

Comment: On http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html


There is this example: [edit] couldnt post code here, but if you go to the link and see the example with doctrine namespace you will see what I meant

I wonder if that means you can have namespace different from file structure?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the last code block, this works because they tell the class loader where to look for the class files. So if your `MyClass` is in the `/plugin1/lib` dir you have to register this namespace explicitly. But you can't register classes from `/plugin1` and `/plugin1/lib` in the same namespace.